# Move Info box or tooltip as mouse moves

Tags: jquery, hover

I have made a query to show a Info box or you can say tooltip on mouse over, but not getting how should I move that box on moving of mouse pointer. Below is my code:

```
$(".info img").hover(function(e){
    $("#dialogbox").show();
}, function(){
    $("#dialogbox").hide();
});

<div class="info"><img src="images/i.jpg" alt="info" /></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set its position via `.css()` when the mouse moves:

```
$("#dialogbox").css('position', 'absolute');

$(".info img").mousemove(function(e) {
  $("#dialogbox").css({'left': e.pageX, 
                       'top':  e.pageY});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mousemove method of jquery. You can get the current location of the mouse pointer and set those coordinates to "top" and "left" values of relevant div. Set "position" attribute of the div to "absolute". Something similar to following code.

```
$(".info img").mousemove(function(event) {

$("#dialogbox").css({"top":event.pageY , "left":event.pageX});

});
```